# How do I prove this limit does not exist: $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} $

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I prove that this limit does not exist?

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} $$

My attempt:

When you approach from from left towards zero , say i take -0.00000000000001 . i substitute in expression i get (-1) . But if i take 0.000000000001 and substitue i get (=1) (by applying L'Hop) . But if i dont do this and apply L'Hop straighaway i get 1 .

Comment: how about making the substitution $y=e^{1/x}$? I haven't tried it but it may be fruitful

Comment: @Joao Issue remains  same

Comment: Ahh ok never mind sorry.

Comment: Replace $\frac{1}{x}$ by $y$ and change the limit to $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty}$. That should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation of the limit between the lines below is wrong. L'Hopital's rule does not apply. See the edit at the end of this answer for the reason why.

---

We have

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

where both of the following limits do not exist:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x)$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} g(x)$$

Thus we may apply L'Hôpital's rule to get

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$$

We find the derivatives

$$f'(x)=g'(x)= -\frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}$$

Since $f'(x) = g'(x)$ we notice $$\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}=1$$

This implies

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} 1 = \boxed{1}$$

---

EDIT: I think L'Hôpital's rule actually doesn't apply, because of a subtlety in the conditions for its application. Looking at the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), one of the conditions is that the limits of $f$ and $g$ are $\pm \infty$, but in your case the limit of $f$ and the limit of $g$ are both nonexistent (not infinity because on one side they are $\pm 1$ and on the other they are $\infty$).

Comment: But doing without L'Hopital limit does not exist . This is my main concern

Comment: No. The limit *does* exist regardless of whether you apply L'Hôpital's rule. The rule is simply a way to make it easier to find *what* the limit is, since both the numerator and the denomenator of the fraction don't converge.

Comment: It may be helpful to consider a simpler example: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{2x}{x+1}$$ Both the numerator and the denomenator of that fraction diverge, but the limit of the fraction exists and is equal to $2$. You can derive that using L'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: When you approach from from left towards zero , say i take -0.00000000000001 . i substitute in expression i get (-1) . But if i take 0.000000000001 and substitue i get 1 (by applying L'Hop) . But if i dont do this and apply L'Hop straighaway i get 1 .

Comment: @JessicaGtb Oh I see the problem now. I will try to find the reason.

Comment: Mukherjee .Yes this question certainly deserves a vote up :)

Comment: I think the reason is that L'Hopital's rule does not apply. $f(x) = e^{1/x}$ does not have a limit that is $0$, $\infty$, or $-\infty$, as is the requirement. Rather, it has a limit that is nonexistent *and* not equal to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: mukherjee .In L'Hop limits from both sides have to be equal to form you mentioned ?

Comment: No, they don't have to be equal. The reason, as I mentioned in the edit for my answer, is that the limit of the top (or $f(x)$) has to equal $0$, $\infty$, or $-\infty$. The limit for the bottom also has to do this. But neither do, since the limit of $f(x)$ doesn't exist. L'Hopital's rule requires the limit of the denominator and numerator to equal zero or *not exist in a specific way*: be $\pm \infty$. But your denominator/numerator don't go to $\pm \infty$.

Comment: Mukherjee i see ,Thanks for kind help

Comment: @JessicaGtb No problem, I apologize for being wrong initially ... good question

Answer (score 1):

Look at limits from the right and left. The reason for the difference is that $\lim_{x\to0+}\frac1x=\infty$, while $\lim_{x\to0-}\frac1x=-\infty$:
\begin{align*}&\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}=\lim_{x\to0+}\frac{1-\frac1{e^{1/x}}}{1+\frac1{e^{1/x}}}=\frac{1-\frac1\infty}{1+\frac1\infty}=\frac{1+0}{1-0}=1\\
&\lim_{x\to0-}\frac{e^{1/x}-1}{e^{1/x}+1}=\frac{e^{-\infty}-1}{e^{-\infty}+1}=\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1\end{align*}
So the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: I was saying that it does not exist .But L'Hopital was screwing whole thing up

Comment: The reason is that L'Hopital's rule does not apply. I think it is because of what I said the reason was.

Comment: @JessicaGtb You can use l'Hopital only on limits of type $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$, so you can't do it here!!!

Comment: @user2345215 But i am still confused  regd this . Isn't this (original question ) $ \frac\infty\infty $ form

Comment: @JessicaGtb No. When $x$ is small and negative, $1/x$ is lange and negative, so $e^{1/x}$ becomes very small.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} $$

Seperate into two limits

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} $$
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} $$

Substitute $1/x=y$

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{y} - 1}{e^{y} + 1} $$
$$\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{e^{y} - 1}{e^{y} + 1} $$

Substitute $e^y=z$

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} $$
$$\lim_{z\rightarrow 0} \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} =\frac{0-1}{0+1}=-1$$

Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} =-1$

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac{z - 1}{z + 1} =\frac\infty\infty$$

Use L'Hospital

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow \infty} \frac11=1$$

Therefore $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1}=1$

We have now shown that the left and right limits are not equal, therefore the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1}= \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} \tanh\left(\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)=1$

$\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1}= \displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow 0-} \tanh\left(\dfrac{1}{2x}\right)=-1$

Comment: I got same answer with L'Hopital .But when doing otherwise limit doesn't exist . Your answer is apparently no more than what i did

Comment: @user170039 Why do you assume $x \rightarrow 0$ is the same thing as $n \rightarrow \infty$? Why not $n \rightarrow -\infty$?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee: Edited. Please check the corrected proof.

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1}= \displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^{y} - 1}{e^{y} + 1} =1$ Note this result is the same as the result obtained using L'Hospital's rule

$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^-} \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1}= \displaystyle \lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{e^{y} - 1}{e^{y} + 1} =-1$

They are not equal. So by definition the limit doesn't exist.

Also note L'Hospital's rule doesn't apply for the second limit,, since $\lim_{x\to 0^-}e^{1/x}=0$, so it's not the form for L'Hosptial's rule.

Answer (score 0):

Let $$f(x) = \frac{e^{1/x} - 1}{e^{1/x} + 1} = 1 - \frac{2}{e^{1/x} + 1}.$$  Thus in order to characterize the limiting behavior of $f$ as $x \to 0$, it suffices to consider the behavior of $g(x) = e^{1/x}$ as $x \to 0$.  However it is obvious that $$\lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x) = \infty$$ whereas $$\lim_{x \to 0^-} g(x) = 0,$$ thus the two-sided limit fails to exist; consequently, the limit of $f$ at $0$ also fails to exist.  In any sufficiently small neighborhood of $0$, the value of $f$ for negative $x$ tends to $-1$, but for positive $x$, the value of $f$ tends to $1$.

The reason why L'Hopital's rule does not apply is simple:  as $x \to 0^-$, $f(x)$ is not an indeterminate form.