# Limit of $(1-e^2)/(1+e^2)$ as $x$ approches negative infinity

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

So, I am having trouble solving this limit. I have racked my brain many times to solve it. Any help is appreciated.

$$
  \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1-e^2}{1+e^2} 
$$

Comment: Do you mean to have $e^x$? The function as given has no $x$ dependence.

Comment: What exactly have you tried before? Assuming you mean $e^x$ rather than $e^2$, this is a very straightforward problem.

Comment: similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1032039/how-do-i-prove-this-limit-does-not-exist-lim-x-rightarrow-0-frace1-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1-e^x}{1+e^x}$$ then the limit is equal to 1, since $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} e^x=0$$ If you did actually mean $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} \frac{1-e^2}{1+e^2}$$ then since $\frac{1-e^2}{1+e^2}$ is independent of x, the limit is simply equal to $\frac{1-e^2}{1+e^2}$.